# how can I set python version through config settings in package.json file?

Tags: reactjs, python-2.7, package.json

My NPM install node modules require python 2.7 version to be passed as parameter. For all these node modules I want to pass --python=python2.7
Now I want to set it through config itself. Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I added the below line of code and it worked:

```
"preinstall": "npm install --save react react-dom webpack@3.10.0 --python=python2.7"
```